# What is the best way to disable ehcache in JHipster

Tags: java, mysql, database, ehcache, jhipster

I want EHCache in production, but not in development as I tend to fiddle with database records in development.

The only thing I came across after searching is this JVM option to disable cache completely `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true`, but somehow this does not appear to be the ideal solution.

Best would be to have an option in **application-dev.yml**. I tinkered with **timeToLiveSeconds** and kept it low (1), but it did not seem to have any effect.

I tried to add an api in my REST service like this, but it did not seem to have any effect either:

```
/**
 * GET  /clearCache -> Clear Cache
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/clearCache",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<String> clearCache() {
    CacheManager.getInstance().clearAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Also, a corollary to this same question, I put a debug breakpoint in **CacheConfiguration.java** here, but it never seems to get hit.

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is my full log on startup with fast boot:

```
[INFO] mypackage.Application - Starting Application on Lenovo-PC with PID 7408 (D:\projects\app\target\classes started by lenovo in D:\projects\app)
[DEBUG] mypackage.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.6.RELEASE
[DEBUG] org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
[DEBUG] mypackage.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [mypackage.Org]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [mypackage.Workflow]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [mypackage.Department]; using defaults.
...
...
...

[DEBUG] mypackage.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server
[INFO] mypackage.Application - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev, fast]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the CacheConfiguration class, you'll see:

```
@Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST)
public class CacheConfiguration {
```

So if you use fast profile, caching is disabled, so either you use this profile or you change annotation to enable caching only in prod profile.

```
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)
public class CacheConfiguration {
```

You're right, the ehcache code where the WARN log is issued creates a cache anyway and it does it for your 3 entities: Org, Workflow and Department.

```
        if ( cache == null ) {
            LOG.unableToFindEhCacheConfiguration( name );
            manager.addCache( name );
            cache = manager.getEhcache( name );
            LOG.debug( "started EHCache region: " + name );
        }
```

I'm not sure the cache is used for entities as our configuration is not run but anyway even the warning is not satisfying, there's probably something missing in our configuration to avoid it.

Could you please [open an issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues) ?

Comment: I have used `--spring.profiles.active=dev,fast` all along, but I think caching was not disabled until I set the environment flag `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried `--spring.profiles.active=dev,fast` and I did not get the "Starting Ehcache" logging from CacheConfiguration. Are you sure you passed the profiles option in program args and not in JVM args? Have you tried with `mvn -Pfast spring-boot:run`?

Comment: I have edited my original question and added my log with fast boot. You can see that though "Starting Ehcache" is not there, Ehcache is still giving that warning and I do think it is running. When I add the specific JVM arg `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true`, that part of the log is mentioning that it is being suppressed.

Comment: Edited answer to ask you to create an issue

Comment: The current jhipster app (3.5.0) doesn't have the "fast" profile anymore, but this tip still stands, as you can easily add the profile restrictions to the configuration class-